# How do I combine nodes with the same node type from different matched patterns into a single column or collection?

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm creating a social network for learning Neo4J. We have users and their followers, posts. We want merge two statements.

**Goal: list of posts including yours and those you follow in chronological order.**

1. My posts
2. My following users posts

We tried **OR** and **RETURN p+l as posts** and **Serverside language merging (Order Problem)**

How I can create this Cypher statement?

**Labels and Relations**

- User

  - username
- Post

  - text

(User)-[f: FOLLOW]-(User)

(Post)-[p: POSTED_BY]-(User)

**Edit**

Also we tried this Cypher

`match (cur_user: User {username: 'ahmetsa'})-[:FOLLOW]->(others: User)<- [:POSTED_BY]-(p: Post)
match ( l: Post) - [:POSTED_BY]->(cur_user: User {username: 'ahmetsa'})
return p+l`

but makes type error

**Type mismatch: expected Collection but was Node (line 3, column 10 (offset: 177))
"return p+l"**

---

**Solution**

`Match (cur_user: User {username: 'ahmetsa'})-[:FOLLOW]->(others: User)<- [:POSTED_BY]-(p: Post) With cur_user,p
Match ( l: Post) - [:POSTED_BY]->(cur_user)
Return collect(p) + collect(l) as posts`

Comment: Why don't you share the nodes you're referring to, the relationship you've created between them, the Cypher queries you've tried, and the desired output that you're hoping to get?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: @InverseFalcon added labels and relationships between them

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "merging your posts with your followers posts". What exactly does that mean to you, and can you provide an example of what the desired output might look like?

Comment: I publish posts and my follows also publishing posts. I'm creating feed list(my posts+others).

1. My Post (newest)

2. My Friend's Post

3. My Friend's Post
4. My Post
5. My Friend's Post(oldest)

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a single column or list of posts including yours and those you follow in chronological order.

Comment: Exactly. I'm adding this to question with editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge your two statements using `WITH`:

```
Match (cur_user: User {username: 'ahmetsa'})-[:FOLLOW]->(others: User)<- [:POSTED_BY]-(p: Post) With cur_user, p
Match ( l: Post) - [:POSTED_BY]->(cur_user)
Return collect(p) + collect(l) as posts
```

`WITH` allows you to pass variable to the next query part so you can use it without matching it again.

Comment: It was my understanding that collections could be added together like this, but not nodes (I get an error when attempting this kind of operation)

Comment: I changed the query by adding a conversion to collection before + operation, this should work fine.

Comment: Type mismatch: expected Collection<Node> but was Node (line 4, column 10 (offset: 193))

Also this should be Order problem

Comment: Now you just need the posts sorted. You can use the [APOC Procedures library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_helpers) for this, assuming the existence of a timestamp property, postTime: `RETURN apoc.coll.sortNodes(posts, 'postTime') YIELD value as posts`. Alternately, after doing the collecting and adding you can UNWIND posts to get them back into rows, then return the posts sorting by the post time.

Comment: While the ideal would be to union both your posts and your followers' posts, then order by posted time, Neo4j 3.0.4 doesn't currently have support for a `UNION WITH` to allow for post-union operations, such as sorting or limiting the entire union instead of just the individual parts making up the unioned whole. Until that sort of feature is added, collecting both into lists and adding them together is the best approach.

Comment: But this makes `Type mismatch: expected Collection<Node> but was Node` error right now (without ordering)

Comment: The query was changed. Ensure you're doing a collect on both post variables when you're adding them together, that changes them into collections.

Comment: `With cur_user` should be changed to `With cur_user,p`. Its make **Variable `p` not defined** error. I'm trying new query, I will try order and feedback

Comment: New query works well, I'm adding this to question. I'm tying ordering

Comment: I fixed the query, sorry for the error. To order you need a property on each post that stores the creation date as timestamp, else you'll be able to order using post name only.